# Do 643,000 Americans go bankrupt every year due to medical bills?

Tags: economics, healthcare

I've been seeing a specific graphic circulating all over Instagram for the past few days. Here's [Kim Kardashian](https://www.instagram.com/kimkardashian/?hl=en) posting it on her story.

[image]

Two things seem odd about this graphic. The first is the 643,000 figure. I know that the American Health Care System is dysfunctional, but that's pretty striking.

But more striking is the fact that all of these other countries supposedly have no one going bankrupt from medical bills. Are these claims true?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[Snopes has already tackled this.](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/643000-bankruptcies-in-the-u-s-every-year-due-to-medical-bills/)

> Using some very specific analyses, one could make the case that (at least within the last several years) about 643,000 Americans declared bankruptcy annually due to medical bills. But the accuracy of those analyses is open to question, the playing field has changed significantly since they were undertaken (due to the implementation of the ACA), and it’s far from an absolute that the other countries listed in the meme experience zero medical-related bankruptcies.

Also it is not necessarily true that there are zero bankruptcies due to medical costs in the other countries (though the US is definitely the leader). None of the countries cover 100% of all possible medical costs, and some people choose to do medical procedures that are not covered at their own expense.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98383/discussion-on-answer-by-djclayworth-do-643-000-americans-go-bankrupt-every-year).

Comment: Snopes barely touched on a critical problem with the original study--what that number actually is is the number of bankruptcies that involve at least one reasonably recent medical bill.  When you apply stricter standards as to what counts as a medical bankruptcy you get **far** lower numbers.

Answer (score 65):

> But more striking is the fact that all of these other countries
>   supposedly have no one going bankrupt from medical bills. Are these
>   claims true?

**Not for Canada.**

There's [a claim on this site](https://www.bankruptcy-canada.ca/causes-of-bankruptcy-in-canada) -- which, admittedly, does look kind of dodgy -- that medical expenses are **the third leading cause** for personal bankruptcy in Canada.  I'm still trying to find a better source on this.

More (apparently) legitimately, [Health issues and health care expenses in Canadian bankruptcies and insolvencies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24684082) (Int J Health Serv. 2014;44(1):7-23) surveyed Canadian debtors and found, among other things,

> 6.9 percent had bills over $5,000 (all amounts in Canadian Dollars). Prescription drugs were cited as the costliest medical expense by
>   two-thirds of debtors reporting bills > $5,000, with dental bills
>   cited by 22.2 percent.

On the whole, it seems very likely that there is a greater-than-zero number of Canadians who "go bankrupt" due to, at least in part, medical bills.

Comment: I can add anecdotal evidence to support the fact that > 0 people in Canada have gone bankrupt from medical bills (not me, but a friend).  Normally, anecdotal evidence is pretty worthless, but this is a specific case where it actually means something.

Comment: @Gryphon We called it "proof by counterexample"; it works for all hypotheses that say "for every/no x holds y".

Comment: Typically Canadian bankruptcy from medical expenses is because of treatment that the government system refuses to pay for, and usually this non-payment is well justified. Some people fly to Mexico for controversial untested treatments.  Others buy drugs that will triple their chances of surviving another year, but that means three chances rather than one chance in a million. I recently spoke to a financial professional that told me about one of his clients.  She spends $10,000 per month for a single injection.  She can afford it now, but if she's still alive in a few years, she'll be bankrupt.

Comment: @RayButterworth No, typically Canadian bankruptcy from medical expenses is (as cited IN THE ANSWER RIGHT ABOVE) prescription drugs and dental bills -- like, 80%+ of the 7% of bankrupt people with significant medical debt.  That doesn't leave much room for your "Typical" claim.

Comment: @Yakk, my example was someone paying $10,000 per injection because the health system won't pay for it.  It *is* a prescription drug, but one that isn't considered effective enough for insurance to provide it.

Comment: I would argue this should be selected as top answer over the snoopes one.  This one definitively proves the statement false, where as the other question shines a high degree of doubt, but does not definitively prove the statement false.

Comment: Typically, I make up something and say that it is typical. Typically, this works.

Comment: @dsollen Except, this answer does not answer the first part of the question ("Is it true that 643,000 Americans go bankrupt each year due to medical bills?"), only the second part ("Is it also true that, for the other countries listed, 0 people go bankrupt each year due to medical bills?").  Both answers are valuable, but this one addresses the lesser part of the question, and the accepted answer addresses the main portion

Comment: Important to note that all of the medical-related things Canadians go bankrupt over, Americans do too. However, things like ER visits cost $0 so no Canadian will ever go bankrupt from that alone. Can't say the same for the ambulance ride though, or the wheelchair, or the hotel stay if the nearest surgical hospital is in another province. No matter where you are in the world, being sick isn't cheap.

Answer (score 45):

> But more striking is the fact that all of these other countries
>   supposedly have no one going bankrupt from medical bills. Are these
>   claims true?

### 0 is totally untrue for Germany.

I first must point out, that Germany doesn't have **free** health insurance in that sense. It has by law **mandatory** health insurance, i.e. everybody is forced to be insured. Nobody is allowed to opt out and be uninsured.

While salaried employees pay one half of the insurance cost by themselves (via direct deduction from their paycheck) and the other half is paid by their employer, those unemployed and on social benefits get it completely paid by the state.

That leaves self-employed people ([of which there are about 4 million](https://www.bmas.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/PDF-Publikationen/Forschungsberichte/fb514-selbststaendige-erwerbstaetigkeit-in-deutschland.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1)), who must completely pay by their own, **but often can't afford this and are indebted**. As of late 2018 there was a total debt of [8.21 billion €](https://www.aerztezeitung.de/politik_gesellschaft/krankenkassen/article/961671/beitragsschulden-kassen-laufen-82-milliarden-euro-hinterher.html) against the public insurers alone. Especially low paid solo self-employed (parcel couriers, those in the gig economy, etc.) are a problematic group here.

The situation is even worse in that if you actually go bankrupt (the term is "Privatinsolvenz", which is similar to filling for Chapter 7 in the US) you are not off the hook. Your health insurance provider will [regularly argue that any debts against him are exempted of being discharged via the bankruptcy process](https://www.ra-franzke.de/privatinsolvenz/faq/nix-schuldenfrei/) and that those debts are only forgiven after 30 years. So for the affected people, bankruptcy might not even be a solution.

### What is the number for Germany then?

It seems like there are no statistics available that split out the number of bankruptcies by reason. Therefor I can only assure you that the number is >0 by pointing out that:

- As elaborated above, there is a lot of debt related to health insurance.
- I personally know people who filed for bankruptcy for this reason.
- If you google for "[privatinsolvenz krankenkasse schulden](https://www.google.de/search?q=privatinsolvenz%20krankenkasse%20schulden)" (bankruptcy + health insurance + debt) you find lots of pages of specialised lawyers, posts of public counseling services, etc. who are giving advice or are offering their services regarding filing for bankruptcy for those who are indebted to their health insurance.

---

(Sorry, all sources in German.)

Comment: This is a good proof by counterexample.  I also want to applude you, as a new contributor, for making sure to properly provide links to back up your claims

Comment: Regarding no statistics being available: It might be impossible to objectively create a statistic for how often this happens. When someone goes bankrupt, then a 377.85 € fixcost per month can't possibly be the *only* reason they went bankrupt. They could just as well blame the cost of food, various forms of taxes, the high rents or whatever reason was responsible for their self-employment not working out the way they thought it would. It was a combination of several factors. Which straw exactly was it which broke the camel's back? Impossible to determine.

Comment: @Philipp Absolutely true. I think the only think you might say with absolute certainty, is that the reason for all private bankcruptcies is that these people didn't have a high enough income to fullfill their financial responsibilites. But that of course says nothing. Nonetheless they somehow arrived at the 643.000 number for the US. If you follow down the sources from the OP, you finally  get to [this](https://www.cohealthinitiative.org/sites/cohealthinitiative.org/files/attachments/warren.pdf) 2007 Harvard Study - just in case you are interested in their methodology. :-)

Comment: @s1lv3r The causal link between healthcare cost and personal bankruptcy is a lot easier to make in the US where bankruptcies are often preceded by a sudden single large medical bill which exceeds the personal savings of the debtor. But health insurance costs in a mandatory insurance systems can not be isolated like that.

Comment: But in Germany health insurance is a fixed percentage of your income. If you are low paid or lose your job you pay much less or nothing at all. You are only going to rack up huge debts if you go for one of those expensive "so-called alternative medicine (SCAM)" treatments not covered by your insurance.

Comment: @RedSonja hmmm ... not for everyone. Health care is a really complicated topic, which is why I opted to not try to describe the inner workings of the system in this post at all ... I personally think a fair way to sum it up would be as following: The current system provides a good safety net for the bulk of the population, but there are still cornercases, were people "fall through" that net. If you google for it, as of today there are around 80.000 citizens effectively without health insurance in Germany, albeit the lawmaker intended for this to be not possible.

Comment: The issue of health insurance debt that you raise is very specific to self-employed people. As @RedSonja says, public insurers in Germany charge a percentage of your income, so the costs are never supposed to be a large fraction of your income. The issue with self-employed people has do with how their income is estimated by the public insurers. This is something that can be changed with relatively little effort - they just have to modify the way in which self-employed income is estimated.

Comment: There is also private medical insurance in Germany. They (obviously) raise the monthly payments as insurance holders become older, there were cases reported when retired people could no longer afford it. It is hard to quit such an insurance and (also a contributing factor) it charges you a (in a short time frame) constant sum, regardless of your employment. So, basically, someone is having a good job, and pays for the private insurance, all well. Should they loose the job, they still need to pay the same amount for the insurance. There are some safeguards, but still.

Comment: After getting so many comments, I finally added two sentences explaining the system further - obviously still on a somewhat superficial level - to make sure that for a casual reader the post doesn't unfairly characterize the system as broken, by leaving the fact out, that the majority of the population enjoys the benefit of affordable health care. (@OlegLobachev while a valid point, I still abstained from explaining the difference between private & public insurance, as I feel it wouldn't add to the gist of the post and only make it more complicated.)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding that the numbers in the claim are approximate to a thousand. I don't doubt that they will be more than zero, but at this point we need to know how many, and the examples you give are not good enough evidence.

Comment: @Sklivvz hmmm ... would you mind to explain what in the claim makes you think, the numbers are approximate to a thousand? Personally I would say, they could have added a footnote or added a "approx." or "~", but without that, just "0" is pretty unambiguous ...

Comment: @s1lv3r they are all divisible by 1,000 with no reminder.

Answer (score 20):

The "zero" part is exaggerated for greater effect. It's not accurate, and might even be considered a lie.

- People can always opt to pay for treatment their insurance does not cover.
- In some of these countries people still need to pay (a smaller amount) for medical treatment, and/or for insurance.
- In some of these countries, people still need to pay for medical expenses while abroad (sometimes only while in especially expensive countries).

A direct comparison is difficult because of the different meanings and requirements to qualify for bankruptcies in different countries. A further complication is provided by loss of income due to medical reasons, which makes it hard to properly classify the cause of a bankruptcy, and practically impossible to do so consistently across national borders.

Regarding the numbers for the US, I initially had multiple sources, but found this one summarizes them quite well:

> A popular Facebook meme said that 643,000 Americans go bankrupt each year due to medical costs. [...] Consumer bankruptcies rose from 775,344 in 2007 to 1.5 million in 2010. By 2017, they'd fallen to 767,721. [...] a 2009 Harvard study [...] said 62.1 percent of all bankruptcies
>   were because of medical bills. [...] In 2011, researchers [...] found that out-of-pocket medical costs caused
>   26 percent of bankruptcies. [...] In 2013 [...] researchers
>   declared that 57.1 percent was more accurate. [...] In 2015, [researchers] found that medical bills made 1 million
>   adults declare bankruptcy.
>
> **Who to Believe**
>
> Researchers disagree on how many medical bills cause
>   bankruptcies. The biggest problem in answering the question is that
>   those filing for bankruptcy aren't required to state the reason. As a
>   result, estimates are based on surveys. The methodology differs from
>   study to study. It depends on how the researchers and the survey
>   respondents define medical debt.
>
> Second, a variety of factors cause bankruptcies. Most people with
>   medical debt have other debt. They may also have low income, little
>   savings, and job losses. That makes it difficult to determine whether
>   the bankruptcy was because of medical debt alone. [source](https://www.thebalance.com/medical-bankruptcy-statistics-4154729)

So the 643,000 number is reasonably accurate, but people with strong political bias may be inclined to argue, as demonstrated by [a rebutted Washington Post article](https://www.businessinsider.com/bernie-sanders-washington-post-retract-fact-check-medical-bill-bankruptcy-2019-8?r=US&IR=T).

Answer (score 4):

**The fact that 0 people in Italy went bankrupt because of healthcare bills could well be true** (with caveats - see below).

In Italy healthcare is public and the "healthcare right" (loose translations of Italian "*diritto alla salute*") is written in one of the first article of the [Italian constitution (Italian integral text from the website of the Italian Republic Senate](https://www.senato.it/documenti/repository/istituzione/costituzione.pdf).

> Art.32
>
> La Repubblica tutela la salute come fondamentale diritto dell'individuo e interesse della collettività, 
>   e garantisce cure gratuite agli indigenti.
>   Nessuno può essere obbligato a un determinato
>   trattamento sanitario se non per disposizione di
>   legge. La legge non può in nessun caso violare i
>   limiti imposti dal rispetto della persona umana.

Which roughly translates into English like this (translation is mine - don't expect legally accurate translation - IANAL):

> 32nd article
>
> The [Italian] Republic protects the health as a 
>   fundamental right of an individual and [as a fundamental]
>   interest of the community, and grants gratuitous healthcare to 
>   indigent people. 
>   No one can be forced to undergo a specific sanitary
>   treatment if not prescribed by the law.
>   In no case the law can violate the limits imposed by the
>   respect of the human person.

Letting people go bankrupt because of medical bills needed not only to preserve their lives, but also to let him live a dignified life, would be against the very fundamental principles of our constitution.

People in Italy do have to contribute partially to their healthcare expenses, but only if their income is sufficiently high.

Poor people are exempted. And people with disabilities are exempted for all bills related to their disabilities.

Anyway, the system is fairly complicated and sometimes convoluted, in order to try to prevent abuse and fraud (which is not uncommon).

Healthcare is one of the biggest expense chapter of Italian national budget.

As for the significance of that "0" figure, that is somewhat fuzzy, because in Italy there is no concept of "bankruptcy" for a private person (it is a concept applicable only to companies). Therefore that 0 figure is not provable because there is no data about people "being bankrupt". There is no formal way for a person to apply for "bankruptcy", hence there is no formal certification that a specific person is "bankrupt", let alone the cause of it.

Of course there are statistics about poor people, but they are sample statistics usually. And then there are the data from the census that is held every 10 years, but there is no way to correlate the poverty of a person with the causes. So the initial comparison is somwehat moot.

On the other hand, if you mean that some people could lose a lot of money if they want non-strictly necessary health care, that surely happens in Italy too, especially if you want to get the services of private doctors. But if you spend so much money that you end up turning poor, then you will be automatically eligible for exemption from further expenses, although those expenses must be "authorized" by your "family doctor", which is mandatory to have and which is a public officer. Therefore he wouldn't "authorize", say, an plastic surgery to cope with bad physical appearance.

I said "authorize" in quote because the system is fairly convoluted (really it is a request for an authorization, that then goes to a public specialist doctor which can authorize the thing... ugh!).

The problem here is that there are regions where the public health care is not up to the standards prescribed by the law (according to the constitution). So, to avoid substandard health care, they are forced to travel to other regions to find the suitable public center that can provide the service.

The national health care system will cover the medical expenses, *but usually not any relocation or travel expenses* (it will if the life of the patient is at risk, but anyway the expenses for the relatives are not covered).

So, in the end, if you really mean that there are no people in Italy that lose everything because they have to cover "fundamental or critical healthcare" expenses, that's probably true.

There could well be people whose life has become quite miserable because they had to cope with the idiosyncrasies of our public health care system.

TL;DR

Bottom line:

1. In Italy there is no way to define "bankruptcy" in a clear way for a person, since the concept is not applicable. You can only determine if a person is poor, according to some statistical criteria for poverty.
   So the comparison with countries with a legally-defined "bankruptcy" criteria is somewhat improper.
2. The Italian constitution grants to every people the healthcare they need to live a dignified life. And that healthcare is gratuitous. Hence ***theoretically*** that 0 figure is a real possibility (although practically not provable).
3. As any human endeavor, the implementation of those principles in our constitution is imperfect, so it may be true that some people, due to health problems, have become broke. But, anyway, the Italian system is designed to prevent that.